# Aggregation - relational db mapping

Tags: mapping, aggregation

I've seen an example of an aggregation between A and B, where B is the `whole` class, with multiplicities 0..* on the B end and 5 on A. Can it accurately be represented with relational tables? There should be a m:n AB table, but each value of B should appear exactly 5 times in it. Is it simply represented as an m:n table and when let's say selecting Bs, those that don't appear 5 times in the AB table are filtered out to get only valid data? (Valid from the user's point of view, not the DBMS's). Still doesn't seem right. Are there other workarounds?

And what if the multiplicity on the B end is changed to 1..*, so each A must appear at least once in the AB table? How could the data be accurately represented in a tabular format?